# How to disable navigation animation?

Tags: angular, ionic4, routerlink

I have a project with a tabs component that is working fine until I want to implement navigation within a tab. For example, my TEAM tab has 2 subtabs/sections/pages TACTICS and INFORMATION, and if I'm on my tactics tab and I click this button:

```
<ion-button routerLink="/tabs/team/information">INFO</ion-button>
```

It navigates to that page with an animation. Is there any way to disable that animation? Or does it just happens because something in my code might be wrong?

Part of my tabs.router.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'team',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'tactics',
            children: [{
              path: '',
              loadChildren: () =>
              import('../team-tactics/team-tactics.module').then(m => m.TeamTacticsPageModule)
            },
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'information',
            children: [{
              path: '',
              loadChildren: () =>
              import('../team-information/team-information.module').then(m => m.TeamInformationPageModule)
            }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `routerDirection`.

[In this article](https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-change-with-ionic-4-and-angular-router/) it discusses using `root` to do an animation that looks like its replacing the entire view, which sounds like basically no animation:

```
 <ion-button expand="block" routerLink="/dashboard" routerDirection="root">
   Login
 </ion-button>
```

> We add a block button which has two important properties: routerLink:
>   The link/path that should be opened routerDirection: Determines the
>   animation that takes place when the page changes
>
> After a login, you most certainly want to ditch your initial page and
>   start again with the inside area as a new starting point. In that
>   case, we can use the direction “root,” which looks like replacing the
>   whole view.
>
> If you want to animate forward or backward, you would use forward/back
>   instead.